# Strange iostat numbers

Tags: linux, iostat

I'm experiencing unusual load issue on one of our VM which is on SAN storage.
As a general practice I ran `iostat` on the server got very strange numbers.

```
 avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.17   49.75    0.00   50.08

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     3.00    0.00   0.00 100.03
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     3.00    0.00   0.00 100.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

even if `rkB/s` & `wkB/s` both at 0 it still shows `%util` at 100%.

Let me know if I am misunderstanding the output.

Thanks,
Meghanand.

Comment: Do you have external disks ? ISCSI, NAS ? They are not stats, by takes iowait.

Comment: Well I'm unsure about it since the server is hosted with our provider, the only available information is its using SAN storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after further investigation with our service provider we found the issue was with the shared SAN storage which was running short of iops, after migrating VM to another SAN issue was resolved.

Thanks,
Meghanand